# Code build vs code deploy to run CF stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I have hard time to understand one simple thing. I have different CF stacks. I wish to have a pipeline which will install them.

Am I supposed to do this thanks to code Build, or code Deploy?

Comment: If CF stands for cloud formation, you want code pipeline.  That supports cloudformation as a native build step type

Comment: Ok so I think I undestand, the deploy step in code pipeline is not the same  Code Deploy ?

Comment: nope.  different services, though related